# What is the "not only ... but also" sentence pattern called?

Tags: terminology

> "Not only ... But also"

What is this sentence pattern called in English grammar? How can I find these patterns?

Comment: By watching lots of old British TV comedies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic pattern is called [coordination](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/coordterm07.htm) or [conjunction](http://www.iscribe.org/english/conj.html). It's where two distinct words or clauses are being joined in a single sentence (to compare, contrast, etc.)

There's also a class of words called [conjunctions](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/conjuncterm.htm) (including, for example, *and, but, for, or, nor, yet,* and *so*) which are commonly used in sentences with this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

This pattern together with some others that you can find [here](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/correlative-conjunctions/) is called **correlative conjunction**.